# Why calling selector of the subclass raise error, while the parent(s) certainly have it?

Tags: ios, swift, runtime-error, selector

I'm using JSQMessageViewController for chat UI. The JSQMessageViewController implements `UIScrollViewDelegate`, and having `scrollViewDidScroll:` function.

And then I subclass `JSQMessageViewController` into `MessagesVc`. The `scrollViewDidScroll:` is called correctly without I even need to override it in the `MessagesVc`.

And then I create another subclass of `JSQMessageViewController` as `JSQBaseViewController`. I override the `scrollViewDidScroll:` here, and also calling `super.scrollViewDidScroll:` inside it. My `MessagesVc` now is a subclass of `JSQBaseViewController` instead of `JSQMessageViewController`.

But when I ran the app, now it raise the error: reason: `'-[MyApps.MessagesVc scrollViewDidScroll:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe5ed00aa00'`. Why is this happened? I don't think this error is supposed to happen, right?

EDIT: I tried to override `scrollViewDidScroll:` in `MessagesVc` and it still doesn't work.

Here is the circumstances of the implementation of `scrollViewDidScroll:` override:

```
import JSQMessageViewController

class JSQBaseViewController : JSQMessageViewController {
    ...
}

extension JSQBaseViewController {
    override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        super.scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView)
        ...
    }
}

class MessagesVc : JSQBaseViewController {
    ...
    // still no override implementation of scrollViewDidScroll here
}
```

Call stack:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyApps.MessagesVc scrollViewDidScroll:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe5ed00aa00'

*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001084f01e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000107b85031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108571784 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   UIKit                               0x00000001098df73b -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 295
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001084725f8 ___forwarding___ + 760
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108472278 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    6   MyApps                              0x0000000105362eb3 _T06MyApps21JSQBaseViewControllerC06scrollC9DidScrollySo08UIScrollC0CF + 131
    7   MyApps                              0x0000000105363e2c _T06MyApps21JSQBaseViewControllerC06scrollC9DidScrollySo08UIScrollC0CFTo + 60
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001097a8bcf -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _notifyDidScroll] + 66
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010978eb87 -[UIScrollView setContentOffset:] + 468
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001097ac854 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _setContentOffset:animated:animationCurve:animationAdjustsForContentOffsetDelta:animation:] + 1022
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010a187f35 -[UICollectionView setContentOffset:animated:] + 350
    12  JSQMessagesViewController           0x0000000106f842e5 -[JSQMessagesViewController scrollToIndexPath:animated:] + 2165
    13  JSQMessagesViewController           0x0000000106f83a59 -[JSQMessagesViewController scrollToBottomAnimated:] + 265
    14  JSQMessagesViewController           0x0000000106f83714 -[JSQMessagesViewController finishSendingMessageAnimated:] + 660
    15  JSQMessagesViewController           0x0000000106f83470 -[JSQMessagesViewController finishSendingMessage] + 48
    16  MyApps                              0x000000010584350b _T06MyApps10MessagesVcC13reloadDisplayyyF + 27
    17  MyApps                              0x0000000105843544 _T06MyApps10MessagesVcC13reloadDisplayyyFTo + 36
    18  MyApps                              0x000000010561f713 _T06MyApps10MessagesVcC10dataSourceSayAA9MyMessageCGSgvW + 35
    19  MyApps                              0x000000010561f6c9 _T06MyApps10MessagesVcC10dataSourceSayAA9MyMessageCGSgvs + 233
    20  MyApps                              0x0000000105842fad _T06MyApps10MessagesVcC10reloadDatayyF + 717
    21  MyApps                              0x00000001058434d4 _T06MyApps10MessagesVcC10reloadDatayyFTo + 36
    22  MyApps                              0x00000001055d4744 _T06MyApps10MessagesVcC11viewDidLoadyyF + 2148
    23  MyApps                              0x00000001055d5a94 _T06MyApps10MessagesVcC11viewDidLoadyyFTo + 36
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000109855191 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1215
    25  UIKit                               0x00000001098555d4 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    26  UIKit                               0x0000000109886c6e -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 945
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010989d5e2 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 714
    28  UIKit                               0x000000010989e8cc -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 150
    29  UIKit                               0x0000000109af6bd7 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 231
    30  UIKit                               0x0000000109780808 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1515
    31  QuartzCore                          0x000000010931061a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 177
    32  QuartzCore                          0x000000010931482b _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 395
    33  QuartzCore                          0x000000010929b29f _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 343
    34  QuartzCore                          0x00000001092c8940 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 568
    35  UIKit                               0x00000001096d9f8c _afterCACommitHandler + 272
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108492607 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010849255e __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108476b81 __CFRunLoopRun + 1537
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010847630b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
    40  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001104bea73 GSEventRunModal + 62
    41  UIKit                               0x00000001096b10b7 UIApplicationMain + 159
    42  MyApps                              0x0000000105755ac7 main + 55
    43  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010cf0e955 start + 1
    44  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
```

Comment: Does the crash go away if you mark your overridden method as `@objc`?

Comment: @MichaelHulet no it doesn't. I've add `@objc` to both `scrollViewDidScroll` in `JSQBaseViewController` and `MessagesVc`, and it still produces run time error when opening the MessagesVc screen.

Comment: Does your object derive from `NSObject`? I assume so, otherwise your code wouldn't get do far, but just checking.,..

Comment: How sure are you that JSQMessageViewController implements UIScrollViewDelegate? I don't see anything like that here: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController

Comment: @saagarjha okay that was actually my guessing because when I tried to extend the JSQBaseViewController using `UIScrollViewDelegate`, Xcode told me that the protocol has already been "used". And when I tried to implement scrollViewDidScroll on JSQBaseViewController, Xcode actually tries to correct me into using `override` syntax. `JSQBaseViewController` was a direct subclass from `JSQMessagesViewController`.

Comment: @nielsbot the `JSQBaseViewController` class was derived from `JSQMessagesViewController` which in turn was derived from interface `UIViewController`, which in turn was derived from interface `UIResponder`, which in turn was derived from `NSObject`.

Comment: To me it doesn't look like `scrollViewDidScroll` should be overriden, looks like a delegate method which should only be implemented.

Comment: @AuRis but every class in the line implement the function with the same name. When the subclass implement func with the same as in parent class, I should use override syntax, no?

Comment: @ChenLiYong you are correct. And technically your code is perfectly valid. But if you override a delegate method implementation you have to be absolutely sure whether you must call `super.scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView)` or not, because that may alter the behaviour of your app entirely (depending on the superclass's implementation). That's why I don't override implementations of delegate methods nor do I call them from the class which conforms to those protocols. Instead I add another public method in my superclass which gets called from delegate method and which can actually be overridden.